# What are some use of dense matrices in statistics?

Tags: large-data, matrix

OK, I am not a statistician (Not even close). I am a High Performance Computing researcher and I wanted a few test cases for **Large** (Greater than 5000x5000) Dense Matrices. I had asked [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1108/where-do-dense-matrices-occur) and a few other places but never got any reply from a statistician. I am very much interested in trying out my codes on a statistics problem. Could you suggest an application in statistics where one needs to solve $Ax=b$ for x where $A$ is dense and square.

I would highly appreciate it if you could also give me applications where A has no structure i.e. No symmetry, No Positive-Definiteness etc. But thats not entirely necessary. A large dense matrix with a good application suffices.

I'm sorry if this question appears open or vague but I can't imagine a better place to ask this question.

Comment: A fairly basic example that comes to my mind is R's [lme4](http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/) package for mixed-effects modeling, which relies on sparse design matrices to handle lot of random effects. However, I feel like you are more interested in sparse input, am I right?

Comment: No, I want a Dense matrix A. Ideally, it should be almost full dense with no symmetry

Comment: When you say 'solve $Ax=b$ for dense $A$', do you mean 'solve $Ax=b$ for $x$, where $A$ is dense'?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the bad shortcuts. That is what I mean. For instance, A = rand(5000,5000); b = rand(5000,1); solve(A,x,b);
Assume rand gives a uniform distribution between 1 and 2

Comment: There are generators of regression problems, e.g.
in [scikit-learn samples_generator](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/dev/datasets/index.html),
and there are surely others.
But, correct me, plain $Ax = b$ is pretty fast with Lapack and the like;
there's I think more of a market for robust methods,
large / sparse over / underdetermined systems, ...
Anyway you might also ask
[metaoptimize](http://metaoptimize.com).

Comment: @Denis The intention of my thesis is to show that my codes are faster than LAPACK.

Comment: @Nunoxic, good luck -- but even a factor of 2 is, what, a year and a half of Moore's law ?

Comment: But as LAPACK scales, so will my code. So, the relative speedup will stay even 10 years from now. Eitherways, better algorithms doesn't hurt anybody :P

Comment: Does A have to be square?

Comment: Yes. A needs to be dense and square compulsorily (& Invertible of course). Unstructured is plus.

Comment: You mentioned LARGE matrices. For statisticians, 1000x1000 is probably huge (1000 variables for 1000 people? That's a freaking large and expensive survey, although I can count a few dozen of government surveys of this format). For computer scientists, 1M x 1M may not be large enough to notice the speed differences.

Bottomline: define LARGE, please.

Comment: Done. Large = Greater than 5K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find the [Java Matrix Benchmark](http://code.google.com/p/java-matrix-benchmark/) useful.  The [Matrix Market](http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/searchtool.html) does not seem to have what you want, although it has many examples.

Comment: Although this didn't completely answer my question, it lead me to a possible answer : http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/data/misc/xlatmr/xlatmr.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is large, although I'm not sure if it's dense enough for you. From http://www.grouplens.org/node/73

- MovieLens 100k - Consists of 100,000 ratings from 1000 users on 1700
  movies.
- MovieLens 1M - Consists of 1 million ratings from 6000 users on 4000
  movies.
- MovieLens 10M - Consists of 10 million ratings and 100,000 tag
  applications applied to 10,000 movies by 72,000 users.

Comment: 1. Denseness is of primary importance and I doubt that the matrix formed would be dense.
2. How is this relevant to Ax=b? I need statistical applications not random large statistics.

Comment: The statistical application is collaborative filtering - given a matrix of users x movies, predict the rating that a user will give to a movie that she has not seen yet. Think Amazon.com-style product recommendation. Large matrices of such user-item preferences tend to be sparse, but you could lop off the really long-tail stuff.

Comment: "Large matrices of such user-item preferences tend to be sparse" Density is of prime importance I'm not sure what long-tail stuff is but nonetheless, I am doubtful it would lead to an unstructured full dense matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the application you are seeking would make sense in a statistical context. What you're interested in is a linear regression analysis. $A\in R^{m\times n}$ is a matrix of $m$ measurements in which each row is a single measurement of $n$ variables. Two potential applications with possibly $n>5000$ come to my mind. 1) DNA microarray analysis and 2) analysis of functional MRI data. In any case it will be hard to find data sets with $m>5000$ people (measurements) in it.

However, your requirement of $m=n$ restricts the sense of such an analysis in a principle way. After all statistics is about inferring some underlying, let's say, truth from *noisy* data, i.e., the statistical model implicit to your question is 
$$b=a^Tx + \epsilon$$ 
where $a$ is a single measurement, $x$ are the assumed parameters that you try to find with your analysis and $\epsilon$ is some form of noise. Now you say that $A$ needs to be invertible, i.e., has to be full rank, i.e., measurements $a$ must not repeat, i.e., you only have a single, noise corrupted observation $b$ per $a$ and that is a very bad situation to try to estimate parameters $x$, especially, in the case where the number of parameters exceeds (or is equal to) the number of measurements. Then your model simply fits the noise in the data which is called overfitting.